# Menu items are not appearing in the Layout tab

Tags: android, eclipse

My Eclipse/ADT is running into a problem in which the menu items would not show themselves under the layout tab and I am also unable to add any new item using the Add option. The normal XML view however is working just fine. Has anyone faced the same situation before?

[image: Layout tab not working]

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting Eclipse and or your computer, that usually fixes any problems.